# Find element in array data using createQueryBuilder

Tags: php, query-builder

I have a table ( `shops`) in witch I store data like this: `["bsd1234","qwe9876"]` in a field named `products` and I want to get the `shops` objects that contain a given product using `createQueryBuilder()`.

It should look like this, but I can't find the solution:

```
public function findByProducts($value)
    {
       return $this->createQueryBuilder('s')
            ->andWhere('s.products = :val')
            ->setParameter('val', $value)
            ->orderBy('s.id', 'ASC')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()
            ; 
    }
```

Can you help mw with that?

Comment: Do you have multiple values in one `products` field?

Comment: One products field can contain one or more values( stored as `["bsd1234","qwe9876"]`)

Comment: Yeah ok, don't do that. See [First Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form). You should use a join table like `shops_products` that has one row per shop per product.